Using equal symbol in ggplot2 and getting a true and false graph but I don't want to see the false graph
I'm making a graph showcasing the Daily Average of social media usage plotted against how distracted people are but I only want the plot showcasing an average of more than 5 hours.
I tried adding facet_wrap(~DailyAverage == "More than 5 hours") but I get a TRUE and FALSE graph in the output. I only want to see the "TRUE" graph and not the rest.
This is my code:
df %>%
ggplot(aes(Distracted, Frequency, fill = DailyAverage)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge()) +
geom_text(aes(label=Frequency), vjust=1.6, color="Black", 
position = position_dodge(0.9),  size=3.5) + 
theme_bw() + facet_wrap(~DailyAverage == "More than 5 hours")

enter image description here
I also tried this:
df %>%
ggplot(aes(Distracted, Frequency, 
fill = DailyAverage == "More than 5  hours")) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge()) +
geom_text(aes(label=Frequency), vjust=1.6, color="Black", 
position = position_dodge(0.9),  size=3.5) + 
theme_bw() 

enter image description here
But it still gives me TRUE and FALSE.
I don't know how to only showcase "More than 5 hours"

You should subset your data before plotting. df %>% subset(DailyAverage == "More than 5 hours") %>% ggplot(...)

Or, since you're using the tidyverse, df %>% filter(DailyAverage == "More than 5 hours") %>% ggplot(etc).

As other's have mentioned, you can subset your data and pipe that subset into ggplot. You can also subset within the ggplot function using the base r functionality. Something like: ggplot(df[df$DailyAverage == "More than 5 hours",]) + geom_bar(ect)
